QGIS virtual Layer joins setting
Using QGIS, I´ve created a point geopackage layer (punkte_gnss) and two virtual layers (pGNSS_vL_PvDW,pGNSS_vL_CircleIntersect). Both with separate expressions and symbology/textstyling. But both with same setting in "Joins" property.
Is it possible to open the attribute table on a virtual layer and edit the joined fields?
These should also modified and saved in the main geopackage layer "punkte_gnss". There is an Editable join layer setting, but I can´t modify something in attribute table.
Perhaps it is also necessary to add the expressions inside virtual layer attribute forms for default values or to have these calculated in the main punkte_gnss layer.


It is not possible to edit the content in a virtual layer. Such a layer can be regarded as view (in database terms), which do not carry any data per se.
But depending on your project structure you can edit the underlying point layer. E.g., adding fields to your point layer, change values in your point layer, ...
Those edits should also update in your virtual layer.
If you query data directly from a database and want to edit this layer ('spatial view') you should search for this.

but what means "Editable join layer"?

Or is it possible to open the corresponded feature from the point layer? A trigger, that activate the point on virtual layer and open the joined feature attribute form to change its values. The virtual layer generates a point in distance and I can make the "original point" unvisible. But when I click on the virtual point, it shows me the values, but I can´t change it. When the original is unvisible, it´s hard do find this point.

"Editable join layer" means, what you think it means: the layers are editable and you can upsert/delete data and updates are shown in both layers. But, the layers have to editable beforehand anyway, so it does not work on a virtual layer/view.

OK, this means, when I select the point layer as editable and than click on virtual layer, I can change values in both and delete features?

I have not tested this, but from the description of "Editable join layer" my guess would be that this works not. Both layer have to be editable.

I´ve tested it, it won´t work with virtual layer. I think it will work with other layer types. But is it possible to create link to the joined attribute/feature? In my case I will click on the point on virtual layer and the properties from joined feature (in my case a point in geopackage layer) will open. So I can modify it and the joined virtual layer will be updated. The virtual layer will represent a point wth distance and bearing from a point layer.

You add data to your point data and the update is not shown in your virtual layer? Have you clicked on "Update virtual layer" icon in the attribute table? Have you checked the relationship between layers (e.g., does your virtual layer query data from your point layer, does the query also select the new data, ...)?

no, the updates will shown in virt.layer. But I create a workaround for "move" a point to another position. This is done without geometrie generators. I´ve created a virt. layer with make_point function. This works in Qfield too. Now I have a field in the pointlayer with "showBasePoint". This is my original point. When I click on false, the base point is unvisible (transparent) and only the point of virt. layer is shown with join attributes from point layer. So I can watch the values. But I can´t modify these values, because they are "joined attributes". So I can´t make the base point visible.

So another idea is to create a textfield with a hyperlink to another layer and select the feature. It should automaticly open the attribute form. And all this must work in QGIS and QField. First I´m searching a possibilty to create a feature in QField with a distance/bearing value to move it´s original position. This won´t work. In QGIS I can do this in a second step with generator "project()". This feature is missing in QField, so I must make a virtual layer with make_point.
